# 3D HashMap java get entries

Tags: java, firebase

I'm currently try to build my own elasticsearch (with less more capabilities and experience) to filter my firebase database, I don't use elasticsearch nor Algolia because I want to make all by myself.

Right now I've come up with this method:

1) get all keywords from my child nodes in firebase
2) add them in a 3D HashMap

For now it arranges my data like I want:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Ex.: `"Restaurants" { "Some restaurant Name" { "keywords": "Some,keywords,here" }`

All I want to do now is to print all values as a way to get further in my code.

Here's how I'm trying to print:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    Log.w("MAP =====> ", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry1 : map.get(entry.getKey()).entrySet()) {
                        Log.w("MAP2 =====> ", entry1.getKey() + ": " + entry1.getValue());
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : map.get(entry.getKey()).get(entry1.getKey()).entrySet()) {
                            Log.w("MAP3 =====> ", entry2.getKey() + ": " + entry2.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I can't seem to be able to go further than the first for loop...

Here's my log:

```
W/MAP =====>: Restaurants: {} 
W/MAP =====>: Hikes: {}
W/MAP =====>: Sports: {}
```

As you can see, Logs for "MAP2" and "MAP3" are not showing, How can I iterate trough all?

Thanks in advance,
Good day/evening/night!

PS.: I know that firebase querying exists, I don't want to use `.startAt()` or `.endAt()` ,etc.

Comment: Instead of `map.get(entry.getKey()).entrySet()` use `entry.getValue().entrySet()` and same for the another inner loop

Comment: Thanks but it still returns only the first log...